# Highcharts not working with jQuery 1.8, any workaround?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a scenario where I need to use jquery 1.8, but I facing facing 2 problems with highcharts, the graph line is not visible and zoom functionality is also not working properly. I have downloaded the latest hightcharts js, ie, version 2.3.3, is there any work around for this?

Comment: check browser console for errors thrown. Hard to troubleshoot without knowing error status

Comment: actually there was no browser errors!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

You need to order your jQuery script tags in a particular order, the one you include first will henceforth be referred using `$` and the latter one can be referred using `jQuery` or you could also give a name that you want like `jq172`. Since highcharts internally using `jQuery` you want to the highchart friendly version later.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.jq172=$.noConflict();
</script>
```

You can now use `$` to leverage 1.8.0 features and `jQuery` or `jq172` to use 1.7.2

```
console.log("$: " + $().jquery);
console.log("jQuery: " + jQuery().jquery);
console.log("window.jq172: " + jq172().jquery);
```

prints to console

> $: 1.8.0
>   jQuery: 1.7.2
>   window.jq172: 1.7.2

**[jQuery version conflict | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/Af8yP/)**