# Conflict between Highcharts and JQuery 1.8.2

Tags: jquery, highcharts

the pie chart and line graph i used in my project were working just fine but when I changed the Jquery 1.7.1 to 1.8.2 the lines are not visible anymore and the pie chart not constructed as well. I google and came around this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424610/highcharts-not-working-with-jquery-1-8-any-workaround) but when I try to include the suggested code i get this error

Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Any suggestions???

Comment: Make sure you have proper URL for jQuery library. It looks like jQuery is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you willing to try jQuery 1.9.x? The [Highcharts demo page](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) is using this version of jQuery (you can verify using Chrome dev console or an equivalent), so presumably that version works.